# Are hoisting and reordering the same thing?

Tags: java, java-memory-model

I read from [Effective Java](http://books.google.co.in/books/about/Effective_Java.html?id=Ft8t0S4VjmwC&redir_esc=y) that In the absence of synchronization the following sequence A below can be converted into sequence B by the virtual machine and this is called `hoisting`. I also read somewhere that if variables are not declared as volatile instructions involving the variables  can be reordered . Are hoisting and reordering the same thing?

```
  while (!done)    sequence A     
    i++;

  if (!done)
     while (true)    sequence B
        i++;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [why hotspot will optimize the following using hoisting?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338180/why-hotspot-will-optimize-the-following-using-hoisting)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

They are slightly different.

**Hoisting** means that you have pulled some operation out of a loop because the loop itself does not affect the result of the operation. In your case, you are hoisting the conditional test out of the while loop.

**Re-ordering** means changing the sequence of instructions in a way that does not affect the result. Typically this would be adjacent instructions with no data dependencies, e.g. it does not matter which order you perform the following two statements:

```
int a = x;
int b = y;
```

Comment: simple and _very_ nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

The term "reordering" as it's used in the Java Memory Model refers to all possible optimizations that may affect correctness of improperly synchronized programs.

So, reordering in this sense is a generic term that includes optimizations such as hoisting, effects of out-of-order execution, inconsistencies caused by memory hierarchy (i.e. caches), and so on.

Answer (score 0):

**Reordering** relates to performance of execution where as reordering doesn't impact performance.

**Hoisting** is done to reordering of Memory barrier instructions.