# How synchronized and volatile work in Java memory model?

Tags: java, synchronized, volatile, java-memory-model

In the "*Effective Java*" book:

```
// Broken! - How long would you expect this program to run?
public class StopThread {

    private static boolean stopRequested;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                int i = 0;
                while (!stopRequested)
                    i++;
            }
        });
        backgroundThread.start();

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        stopRequested = true;
    }
}
```

the *backgroundThread* will not stop after one second. Because *hoisting*, the optimization in JVM, HotSpot server VM does.

You can view this in the following topic:
[Why HotSpot will optimize the following using hoisting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9338180/why-hotspot-will-optimize-the-following-using-hoisting).

The optimization goes like this:

```
if (!done)
    while (true)
        i++;
```

there are two ways to fix the problem.

#### 1. Use *volatile*

```
private static volatile boolean stopRequested;
```

The function of *volatile* is
- forbid *hoisting*
- it guarantees that any thread that reads the field will see the most recently written value

#### 2. Use *synchronized*

```
public class StopThread {

    private static boolean stopRequested;

    private static synchronized void requestStop() {
        stopRequested = true;
    }

    private static synchronized boolean stopRequested() {
        return stopRequested;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
                throws InterruptedException {
        Thread backgroundThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                int i = 0;
                while (!stopRequested())
                    i++;
            }
        });
        backgroundThread.start();

        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
        requestStop();
    }
}
```

The above code is right in the *Effective Java* book, its equivalent that use `volatile` to decorate the `stopRequested`.

```
private static boolean stopRequested() {
    return stopRequested;
}
```

If this method omit the `synchronized` keyword, this program isn't working well.
I think that this change cause the **hoisting** when the method omit the `synchronized` keyword.
Is that right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To clearly understand why this happens you need to know something about what happens at a deeper level. (This is basically an explanation of what is called a happens-before relationship, with a language that I hope is more understable for the reader).

Normally variables are present in the RAM memory. When a thread needs to use them it take them from the RAM and put them in cache so it can access them as fast as possible until needed.

Using **`volatile` force a thread to read and write variables directly from RAM** memory. So when many thread are using the same `volatile` variable all them see the last version that is present in RAM memory and not a possible old copy in cache.

When a thread enter a `synchronized` block it needs to take control of a monitor variable. All other threads wait until the first thread exit from the `synchronized` block. To ensure that all thread can see the same modifications all variables used in a **synchronized block are read and written directly from the RAM** memory instead from a cache copy.

So if you try to read the variable `stopRequested` without a `synchronized` method or without a `volatile` keyword you can read a possible old copy of it that is present in the cache.

To solve this you need to be sure that:

- all threads are using `volatile` variables
- or all thread that access those variable are using a `synchronized` block.

Using the method

```
private static boolean stopRequested() {
   return stopRequested;
}
```

without a `synchronized` keyword and when `stopRequested` is not `volatile` means that you can read the value of `stopRequested` from a cache copy that is invalid.

Comment: Thanks, i wonder that if using `volatile` or `synchronized`, it also forbid **hoisting** ? if it not, this program will run correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It is not . When a synchronized method exits, it automatically establishes a happens-before relationship with any subsequent invocation of a synchronized method for the same object. **This guarantees that changes to the state of the object are visible to all threads**. As to your question above , both `volatile` and `synchronized` guarantee the visibility which makes it stops after 1s.

Comment: yes you is right. But i ask if synchroized is omitted in method `stopRequested`,but this keyword in method `requestStop` still exist.So executing  requestStop mehtod can change the value of `stopRequested` and be seen by other thread. if the `hoisting` do not happen,i think this program is running correctly.

Comment: @Edward  `synchroized` of `stopRequested` guarantees that every thread  entered the method can see the newest variables `synchroized` blocked , it can not be omitted . Are you think of that once `synchroized` , the blocked variables changes are always visiable ?

Answer (score 0):

**Declaring a volatile Java variable means:**

The value of this variable will never be cached thread-locally: **all reads and writes will go straight to "main memory"**;

**Declaring a synchronization means:**
So, where volatile only synchronizes the value of one variable between the thread memory and the "main" memory, synchronized synchronizes the value of **all variables between the thread memory and the "main" memory** in method and locks and releases a monitor to control the ownership between multiple threads.